# How to pass custom pojo as parameter to the interface method call in rxjava2 Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

**Current code**

```
    Observable.from(listMovie)//list of movie
            .flatMap(new Func1<Movie, Observable<FavMovieRes>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<FavMovieRes> call(Movie movie) {
                    return moviesAPI.makeMovieFav(userId),
                    sessionId, new MakeMovieFav("movie", movie.getId(), movie.isFavList()));
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<FavMovieRes>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(FavMovieRes favMovieRes) {

        }
    });
```

In above code I am passing Movie object list to the Observable and perform an operation on each movie instance in list when result gets from the API I want to change some database regarding that movie instance how can I get each Movie instance in OnNext() as well as onError method of subscribe method.
**what I want is**

```
Observable.from(listMovie)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Movie, Observable<FavMovieRes>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<FavMovieRes> call(Movie movie) {
                        return moviesAPI.makeMovieFav(String.valueOf(SharedPreferenceDataManager.getUserId(SyncFavListPeriodicTask.this)), SharedPreferenceDataManager.getSessionId(SyncFavListPeriodicTask.this), new MakeMovieFav("movie", movie.getId(), movie.isFavList()));
                    }
                }).subscribe(new Subscriber<FavMovieRes>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e,Movie movie) {//or MakeMovieFav makeMovieFav

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(FavMovieRes favMovieRes,Movie movie) {//or MakeMovieFav makeMovieFav

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a List and want to process each received item for another single async operation. For this case you can flatmap each result.

`flatMapIterable` means that it will split each item in the list as Observable to the next Operation in your Stream. `flatMap` means that it will do an operation on the value received.

If you want to put the results back together you can use `toList` after flatMap.

You need to create an Observable (Operation) for your **flatmap**.

**Kotlin:**

```
Observable.just(data)
        .flatMapIterable { it }
        .flatMap{ moviesAPI.makeMovieFavObservable(whatEver) }
        .subscribe( ... , ... , ... )
```

**Java (Untested)**

```
Observable.just(data)
            //parse each item in the list and return it as observable
            .flatMapIterable(d -> d) 
            // use each item and to another observable operation
            .flatMap(data -> Observable.just(moviesAPI.movieStuff(data)))                         
            // use each result and put it back into a list
            .toList() // put the result back to a list
            // subscribe it and log the result with Tag data, throw the error and output when completed
            .subscribe( data -> Log.d("Data", "Data received "+ data), 
                        error -> error.printStackTrace(), 
                        () -> Log.d("Completed", "Completed")
            );
```

Comment: No that I already achieve I want to get the data which I process on not the data after the process.In this case the each Result object I want it in a method call(Result result) and call(Throwable throwable, Result result).